# two output values through pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I had to write the following function, which returns two output values.

In order to do so I used a pointer for the second output value of the quotient. However when I wanted to test it with an input it seemed to be crushing. The code is:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int div( int n, int m, int *quotient)
{
    int d = 0;
    
    while (n >= m) {
        n = n - m;
        d++;
    }
    *quotient = d;
    
    return n;
}   

int main(void)
{
    int *p;
    int rest;
    
    rest = div(7, 2, p); 
    printf("n - %i, d - %i", rest, p);
    
    return 0;
}
```

would be happy to know how to fix it and why it happened at first place

Thanks for your help

Comment: You need to pass it a pointer *to an actual variable*.  You're passing it a `p` that points nowhere.  Try `int q; rest = div(7, 2, &q);`, or maybe `int q; int *p = &q;`.

Comment: @SteveSummit do you mean declaring another variable and passing it the value of the pointer? Because if so it does not work either. Edit: just saw your edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
int *p;
int rest;

rest = div(7, 2, p);
```

To this:

```
int p;
int rest;

rest = div(7, 2, &p);
```

The problem with your code is that p points some random unallocated place (or is a null pointer if you're lucky). The updated version allocates space for the integer and then passes its address to the function. The function then has a pointer to this address and can write the value there. The memory is allocated on the stack (local variable) and so everything is fine.